# How to load data into a multi column listbox VBA VB6?

Tags: vba, loops, listbox, vb6

I am trying to loop through and load data row by row into a list box and I need different data in multiple columns. I keep getting errors but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The error is:

> "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

It occurs on the first `List1.List(R, Z)`

```
Dim R As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
R = 0
List1.Clear

For i = 3 To 8
STATS = "dynamic data not a string"
If STATS = 0 Then GoTo nexti
NAMEE = "only a string"
REALNAMEE = "for this example"
CREATBY = "to avoid extra code"
CREATEDT = "but is dynamic"
EXT = "a 6th value"
Path = "a 7th dynamically loaded value"


Z = 0
'if we are here lets add item to list.
List1.List(R, Z) = STATS
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = NAMEE
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = REALNAMEE
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = CREATBY
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = CREATEDT
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = EXT
     Z = Z + 1
          List1.List(R, Z) = Path
     Z = Z + 1
    R = R + 1
nexti:
Next i
```

Comment: Feels like Groundhog day.  Not sure I want to keep looking at this question over and over again but here goes... Looks like you made a couple changes I suggested in my last post - but now you've deleted the `List`.AddItem` method that you absolutely need for eah new row. Like I asked before - what LINE gives you the error. Have you define your listbox columns to be 7? Why do you compare STATS = 0 when you're using it as a string? If this is VB6 and not VBA make sure the multiple column  examples you're diawng from match your environment.

Comment: I believe ListView is better suited to what you want to do. But people have used <tab> to separate columns in the list control - if you dare to go that route, here's an example http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?350118-RESOLVED-Columns-property-of-List-box-How-to-use

Comment: it's not groundhog day I deleted last question and made a new one to 
"comply" with rules. I see I still get a negative vote and have no idea why

Comment: If your yet-again-improperly-posed question gets downvoted, will you throw another fit? It's about time you read [ask]. Put together a proper question with a full error message. You can [edit] your post so that you don't have to repost. @dbmitch has been trying to make you do this right, you should start to listen.

Comment: anyway to answer the question.. the strings are not strings. They are dynamically loaded data. I made them strings so that we don't have to get into where the dynamic data comes from. I just want to focus on the issue. The error comes from the first List1.List(R,Z)

Comment: What fit? I read the post and tried my best to comply. Don't know what else to tell you Andras.

Comment: Fit might have been exaggeration on my part, sorry. I just vaguely recall you ranting a bit about getting downvotes and having a problem to solve. It didn't come across well. And deletion+reposting is also off-putting to many (myself included). What matters is that you put your question into proper shape, to make the best of it.

Comment: yes I have 7 columns in this case. It's easy to try different column counts. I've been trying many different things.

Comment: Andras I only deleted to stop the negative votes and to allow time for me to read what you posted before trying again. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: It's OK. Just please [edit] this question now. If it becomes an answerable question as-is (so without reading through your handful of comments), I'll gladly remove my downvote.

Comment: Andras I am not trying to be a smart ass but I really don't know what the objection is to the current post. If I knew I would not hesitate to fix.

Comment: For starters: ["*Include any error messages...*"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ["*Like I asked before - what LINE gives you the error.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796647/need-data-to-load-into-a-multi-column-listbox-vba-vb6-not-working#comment64964547_38796647).

Comment: I have the error message. Maybe I will add a break so it's stands out more.

Comment: Knowing the line number where the error is thrown would really make it easier to answer the question. Please do what you can to provide this information; insert print statements everywhere that echo the line number if you need to.

Comment: `Property List(Integer) As String` it doesnt take 2 arguments (and should highlight the  `R,Z` form as the error).

Comment: Plutonix I thought you could tell it which row and col to use? That's not right?

Comment: ListBox columns are not what you think.  They dont make it a grid.  They cause the data to "snake" down col0, then up to the top and down col1.  BTW, the 2 very, very worst things you can do on SO is a) delete a DV'd Q and b) delete a Q that someone took the time to answer.

Comment: thank you for the information. If I need dynamic data to appear to the user in rows with different data in each col what should I do? I need the rows select-able. I will also need to reference specific data from a col in the selected row.

Comment: see my example. For dynamic data - it's just changing the loop to access recordset fields - but your question doesn't include any reference to recordsets or fields so I won't make something up without an example

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to use a ListBox in VB6 to show multiple columns here's an example of using one. I highly recommend ListView because this is basically a fudge that works for  what you want - just to prove it can be done.

Separating each column by <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters will only display formatting properly if you format each column with fixed number of characters - but THAT is left to YOU to add if you really want to have it look nice.

I've added a second function that shows you how to retrieve the individual columns from the selected row.

```
Option Explicit

Const COLUMN_DELIMITER  As String = vbTab
Const NUM_COLUMNS       As Integer = 7

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim intCol  As Integer
    Dim strRow  As String
    Dim varCols As Variant

    If List1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        strRow = List1.List(List1.ListIndex)
        varCols = Split(strRow, COLUMN_DELIMITER)

        MsgBox "Check Immediate Window for Selected Columns"
        Debug.Print "SELECTED ROW INDEX: " & List1.ListIndex

        For intCol = 0 To UBound(varCols)
            Debug.Print varCols(intCol)
        Next intCol
    End If

End Sub
```

Load the initial list box with random data:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Const NUM_ROWS  As Integer = 10

    Dim intRow      As Integer
    Dim intCol      As Integer
    Dim strRow      As String

    List1.Clear

    ' Create Tab-Delimited List Box
    For intRow = 1 To NUM_ROWS

        ' Start of Row - add first column
        strRow = "Item " & intRow

        For intCol = 1 To NUM_COLUMNS - 1
            strRow = strRow & COLUMN_DELIMITER & "Col" & intCol + 1
        Next intCol

Debug.Print "Adding Row: " & strRow
        List1.AddItem strRow, intRow - 1
        strRow = ""

    Next intRow

End Sub
```

Screenshot of ListBox with multiple "columns":

[image]