# How to add columns in Listbox control in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

Im trying to populate `Listbox` with Columns but I didn't get success.

I populated the `Listbox` with the contents of the following text file `users.txt`:

```
1|Jhon|street 3|12/03/1985 
2|Peter|strt2|29/09/2009
3|Scoby|street 1|11/02/2001
```

Here is my code to populate, as you can see there's a delimiter `|`:

```vb
Public Sub Pathway(way As Variant) 'SET DATABASE FOLDER
     way = App.Path & "\data"
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListbox()
  Call Pathway(way) 'SET FOLDER WAY
  List1.Clear
  
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim sInput As String
Dim iInd As Integer
'- Holds list item information
Dim strList As String


    'To load the ListBox from file:
    fNum = FreeFile
    'List1.Clear
    Open way & "\users.txt" For Input As #fNum
    Do Until EOF(fNum)
       Input #fNum, sInput
     '-====================
        '- Increment item count
        rCT = rCT + 1
        '- Resize array to match item count
        ReDim Preserve nmInfo(rCT)
        '- Add data to the array
        nmInfo(rCT) = sInput
        '- Use  VB string "Replace" function to remove the pipes
        strList = Replace(nmInfo(rCT), "|", Space(1))
        '- Add to listbox
        List1.AddItem strList 'sInput
     '-======================        
    Loop
    Close #fNum

End Sub
```

I would like to ask for your help to add (4) Columns to my Listbox.
I tried the `Listbox` property but it didn't work.

I would like to see it like this:
[image]

Comment: The vb6 listbox doesn't support columns in the way that you're expecting. I'd suggest using a listview control instead or looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796647/how-to-load-data-into-a-multi-column-listbox-vba-vb6) answer.

Comment: IIRC there's a Columns property you need to set to the desired number of columns, and then instead of adding items one by one you populate an array and assign the List property with that array. Then there's another property to display a heading, and you can set individual column widths by comma-separating them, so "0,50,100,100" would hide the value/first column.

Comment: Could be mistaken though, it's been a while =)